# Modelling if condition of multiple estimators in a pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, apache-spark, data-product

How to correctly model a if condition to choose estimator/predictor(linear regression, gbt) to be used in scikit/spark-ml in a single pipeline.

```
if feature_x < constant: 
    result = pipeline1.predict(feature_vector)
else:
    result = pipeline2.predict(feature_vector)
```

Other than modelling it as custom transformer/predictor, is there a alternate way to model it in a pipeline

---